# Error in reading a PDF file C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I want to read pdf than export all data to doc file. I am doing this using a famous library:itextsharp.

However .pdf file has an interesting feature. Therefore result is not good. The .pdf file example is:[image]

As you can see, in pdf file, the choices(A,B,C,D and E) seem like a line. Therefore , result is like this:[image]

How can i do this correctly? how can i write answers with related choices without newline? (I used SimpleTextExtractionStrategy and LocationTextExtractionStrategy. Both of them do not produce proper outputs. This is SimpleText method's  output. This is better than Location. The only problem is that answer and choice are not in the same line)

```
 public string ReadPdfFile(string  Filename)
    {

        string strText = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Filename);

            for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy  ();
                String s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);

                s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)));
                strText = strText + s + "\r\n";

            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return strText;

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: `.pdf file has an interesting future` ...?? what does this mean..? also have you looked at any of the `ITextSharp` examples that they have on their site..?

Comment: it has to be feature.

Comment: I thank you for your attention.

Comment: It's as if you are using the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` instead of the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`, but obviously it's hard to tell as you are not sharing any of your code.

Comment: I used both of them . Both of them do not produce proper outputs.